Do diffeomorphisms map increasingly smaller sets to increasingly "smaller" sets?
Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ be an open set. Let $\phi: \Omega \rightarrow \Omega$ be a diffeomorphism. Suppose $y \in \Omega$ is such that for each $n \in \mathbb N$, $\overline{B(y, 1/n)} \subset \Omega$.
I am curious to know if, decreasing the radius of the ball around $y$, we also get a "decrease" in the images via $\phi$, in the precise sense that for small radii, the boundaries of the images of the interiors get mapped to the images of interiors of balls of large radii:
In other words, is it true that for every $n \in \mathbb N$, there exists $N \in \mathbb N$, $N > n$, such that
$$
\partial \phi( B(y, 1/N)) \subset \phi(B(y, 1/n))
$$
?
I tried to cook up counterexamples, for example $x + \arctan(x)$ on $\mathbb R$, but they didn't work.

Isn't this trivial? $\partial B(y,1/N)\subsetneq B(y,1/N)\subsetneq B(y,1/n)$. Applying the injectivity of $\phi$...

@JulioPuerta By $B(y, 1/N)$ I mean the open ball, so the first inclusion you write is not true.

It does not matter. Include the boundary in a ball with radius between $1/N$ and $1/n$.

@JulioPuerta My apologies, it was indeed trivial the way I asked it, but I meant to ask something else. I meant to ask about the boundary of the image, not the image of the boundary. Please review the question now.

What you have written is still trivial: $\partial \phi(B(y,1/N))) = \phi(\partial(B(y,1/N))) \subset \phi(B(y,1/n))$.
